# SQLite.NET in-memory (:memory:) database MUCH slower than file-based database

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I have some automated tests that are using SQLite.Net-PCL as a backing store. I found that instead of using an actual file, you can pass in ":memory:" as the path for the connection string, to create an in-memory database like so:

```
public class MyRepositoryService : SQLiteAsyncConnection
{
    public MyRepositoryService() 
        : base(() => new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(
                new SQLitePlatformGeneric(),
                new SQLiteConnectionString(
                    ":memory:",
                    false)
                ))
    {
    }
}
```

Much to my surprise, this is MUCH slower than using a regular file. A test that takes ~100ms in a file takes over 1 minute with in-memory. Why?

Not only that, but multiple of my tests suddenly start failing when i switch to the in-memory database - most seem to be related to the tables never being created

Am i really forced to use a file-based database for my unittests?

Answer (score 0):

An in-memory database vanishes when the connection is closed.

So every test creates a new database, and has to recreate all tables again.

Comment: I dont think this is the cause of the slow performance. I clear and recreate the file-based database for every test as well